# Having error on SQL Access when I try to insert data

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-insert

I dont know where I am doing wrong, I am trying to insert data through sql and having an syntax error in the line where I write INSERT. I marked with **bold** where the error it occur!

My code below:

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerTable (
    CustomerId INT NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(25),
    LastName varchar(25),
    Gender char(1),
    Address varchar(100),
    Phone varchar(15),
    DOB Datetime,
    Email varchar(25),
    CONSTRAINT PK_CostumerID PRIMARY KEY (CustomerTable)
);

**INSERT** INTO Customer_Table VALUES(1398,'John','Smith','M','28 Peachtree court','555-B123','1/23/1994','JohnSmith@gmaicom');
INSERT INTO Customer_Table VALUES(1450,'Alex','James','M','43 Jackson Avenue','555-715B','10/11/1974','Alexjames@yahocom');
INSERT INTO Customer_Table VALUES(1890,'Jennifier','Garmer','F','2189 Beverly Hills_Road','555-90B6','11/03/1982','jennifergamer@gmaicom');

SELECT * FROM Customer_Table;
```

Comment: Well, start by _reading_, _researching_, and adequately _describing_ the error.. (minimally, the portion of the error providing context). Also work on a MINIMAL reproduction case. What is the smallest (ie. single) SQL statement to generate the error?

Comment: Which error are you getting? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61567634/edit) to add the entire error message.

Comment: The syntax error it shows me at the word INSERT!!

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no procedural language in MS Access like SQL Server's `tsql` or Postgres' `pgsql` or objects like stored procedures or stored functions, you cannot run multiple SQL statements in ***same*** query in MS Access. This is why the start of second statement raises the first error.

Instead, save each SQL statement that ends in `;` by itself as separate stored queries and then run them in needed sequence either by GUI (i.e., clicking saved query objects) or by code like VBA (but accessible in any other language that can connect to the Access database like Python):

#### SQL

Save as *myCreateTableQuery*

```sql
CREATE TABLE CustomerTable ( 
    CustomerId INT NOT NULL, 
    FirstName varchar(25), 
    LastName varchar(25), 
    Gender char(1), 
    Address varchar(100), 
    Phone varchar(15), 
    DOB Datetime, 
    Email varchar(25), 
    CONSTRAINT PK_CostumerID 
    PRIMARY KEY (CustomerTable) 
);
```

Save as *myInsertQuery1*

```sql
INSERT INTO Customer_Table
VALUES (1398,'John', 'Smith', 'M', '28 Peachtree court',
        '555-B123', CDate('1/23/1994'), 'JohnSmith@gmaicom');
```

Save as *myInsertQuery2*

```sql
INSERT INTO Customer_Table 
VALUES (1450,'Alex','James', 'M', '43 Jackson Avenue',
        '555-715B', CDate('10/11/1974'), 'Alexjames@yahocom');
```

Save as *myInsertQuery3*

```sql
INSERT INTO Customer_Table 
VALUES (1890,'Jennifier', 'Garmer', 'F', '2189 Beverly Hills_Road',
        '555-90B6', CDate('11/03/1982'), 'jennifergamer@gmaicom');
```

Save as *mySelectQuery*

```sql
SELECT * FROM Customer_Table;
```

**VBA**

```vb
' RUNS IN BACKGROUND WITH USER WARNINGS
DoCmd.OpenQuery "myCreateTableQuery"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "myInsertQuery1"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "myInsertQuery2"
DoCmd.OpenQuery "myInsertQuery3"

' OPENS TO SCREEN
DoCmd.OpenQuery "mySelectQuery"
```

**Python**

```py
# RUNS ACTION QUERIES
cur.execute("{CALL myCreateTableQuery}")
cur.execute("{CALL myInsertQuery1}")
cur.execute("{CALL myInsertQuery2}")
cur.execute("{CALL myInsertQuery3}")
conn.commit()

# FETCH RESULTSET AND PRINT TO SCREEN
cur.execute("{CALL mySelectQuery}")
# cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mySelectQuery")

for row in cur.fetchall()
    print(row)
```

Answer (score -1):

Please, try that:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('CustomerTable') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE CustomerTable ( 
        CustomerId INT NOT NULL, 
        FirstName varchar(25), 
        LastName varchar(25), 
        Gender char(1), 
        Address varchar(100), 
        Phone varchar(15), 
        DOB Datetime,Email varchar(25), 
        CONSTRAINT PK_CostumerID 
            PRIMARY KEY (CustomerId));
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM CustomerTable)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CustomerTable VALUES(1398,'John','Smith','M','28 Peachtree court','555-B123','1/23/1994','JohnSmith@gmaicom'); 
    INSERT INTO CustomerTable VALUES(1450,'Alex','James','M','43 Jackson Avenue','555-715B','10/11/1974','Alexjames@yahocom'); 
    INSERT INTO CustomerTable VALUES(1890,'Jennifier','Garmer','F','2189 Beverly Hills_Road','555-90B6','11/03/1982','jennifergamer@gmaicom'); 
END
GO

SELECT * FROM CustomerTable;
GO
```

Comment: I have fixed the names (table name had underscore on inserts and select) and the primary key name was wrong.

Comment: again the only problem it shows at the INSERT in the beginning!

Comment: "GO" statement was missing. If we don't add the go statement TSQL tries to run all at once. Please give it a shot now.

Comment: I have never used the GO Statement before, and still it doesnt let me to use IF statement in the sql access!

Comment: The question is about ms access, while this answer is for ms sql server. These are two different products.

Comment: @KorabIbrahimi the question is the following: "I dont know where I am doing wrong, I am trying to insert data through sql and having an syntax error in the line where I write INSERT. I marked with bold where the error it occur!". I did fix the script and tested on my local environment and it works perfecly. I don't understand your point.

Comment: I just read the accepted answer and now I understand that you're running this over MS Access. I thought you were trying to run this to create the database structure and populate the database. Although you werent clear on the question you posted. Home I was able to help you anyway.